# Infer type function parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am creating a form that has multiple Autocomplete fields, each field uses a different API endpoint to get the options and the response object is unique for each field, here is the type that defines autocomplete field props.

```
type AutoCompleteFieldProps<T> = {
   onInputChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, value: string) => void;
   getSelectedOption: (listOption: T, selectedOption: T) => boolean;
   getOptionLabel: (option: T) => string;
   onOptionSelect?: (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, option: T[]) => void;
}

export type MyFormAutoCompleteFieldProps<T> = Partial<Record<keyof MyFormFields, AutoCompleteFieldProps<T>>>;
```

For the moment I have only one field in the form

```
const autoCompleteFieldProps: MyFormAutoCompleteFieldProps<IBackOfficeUser>  = {
   'usersList': {
      onInputChange: React.useCallback(async (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, value: string) => {
         //....
     }, []),
     getOptionLabel: (value: IBackOfficeUser) => {
        //....
     },
     getSelectedOption: (listOption: IBackOfficeUser, selectedOption: IBackOfficeUser) => {
        //....
     },
     onOptionSelect: React.useCallback((event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, value: IBackOfficeUser[]) => 
     {
        //....
     }, [])
  }
}
```

In case I want to add more fields, I cannot type the props with `MyFormAutoCompleteFieldProps<IBackOfficeUser>`, because the new field will have a different response type.

How can I make this more dynamic ? is there a way to dynamically type the methods in AutoCompleteFieldProps maybe ? something like

```
getSelectedOption: <T>(listOption: T, selectedOption: T) => boolean;
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: Pls, share reproducable example

Comment: Here you go https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-fast-bf6m4?file=/src/index.ts, assume I want to add a new field 'clientsList', P.S I would like to avoid using MyFormAutoCompleteFieldProps<any>

Answer (score 1):

```js
type MyFormFields = {
  usersList: string[];
  title: string;
  clientsList: string[];
};

type FormMap = {
  usersList: IBackOfficeUser;
  clientsList: IClientUser;
  title: unknown;
}

type IBackOfficeUser = {
  userId: number;
  fullName: string;
};

type IClientUser = {
  clientCode: string;
  fullName: string;
};

type AutoCompleteFieldProps<T> = {
  onInputChange: (value: string) => void;
  getSelectedOption: (listOption: T, selectedOption: T) => boolean;
  getOptionLabel: (option: T) => string;
  onOptionSelect?: (option: T[]) => void;
};


type MyFormAutoCompleteFieldProps = Partial<{
  [P in keyof MyFormFields]:AutoCompleteFieldProps<FormMap[P]>
}>

const autoCompleteFieldProps: MyFormAutoCompleteFieldProps = {
  usersList: {
    onInputChange: () => { },
    getOptionLabel: (value) => {
      return "test";
    },
    getSelectedOption: (
      listOption,
      selectedOption
    ) => {
      return false;
    },
    onOptionSelect: (value) => { }
  },
  clientsList: {
    onInputChange: () => { },
    getOptionLabel: (value) => {
      return "test";
    },
    getSelectedOption: (
      listOption,
      selectedOption
    ) => {
      return false;
    },
    onOptionSelect: (value) => { }
  }
};
```

You can just create mapping type. As you might have noticed, I have removed all explicit types from `autoCompleteFieldProps` since it should be infered properly

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiB7ATgW3gSwgGwCYGcoBeKAbwCgooBXfCZfAGQ32AC4pXkMA7AcwDaAXQDclKMAzBsEDl158xVAMbYsPYExbtOwbv2FiAvmPKhIUJGhgBDMMTLja9Law4BJAEI3lAawDyAGaBGMoQAKp0yEpQquqazG5Q7gDCahAakfQxktKyNDy%20PIgA7jzG5Gbg0F4%20AcGhEVEOFFTOyO64HDzUqABG2eKB1NjYAHI2qPny-Mam5jVp8VnILeJxGcApiLjTegoxw6MTU3L7s%20QmlQtQAILUwIjbqGAywBCYOLgACsiIYPgADwAFQAfGsqIgeO4eGAHikABY2fj5AAUADcbNhqHt9HwAJTEcHoxAYXAxPgQYAAZRwEGU71w-jAkihHFRalYzNZPA4wIANJw6QyIEyWRg2VBgYSiOC%20ohEDJkRSqdyJTxGDYBth2f8eXyZeCZopxFC1VDaTIGQB%20XXiyXA4SGqAkslzSpVCxwKyoe6PZ6vKkfLB4X7-Qgkb42ZCSLGA1pQATfKC8KC%20CAgRCBWAIFDoEMEIRsP1PRAvN7Br5hgGAn22MBJoSgy7N8jKKGsKA2B6l8tBz6hv4AjjevMlgMVgc-IcRxxtKKuHQJyHQ2HwpEo9nO0hQIz88RUSnAc0arU4dmY7EQbcHqhQZBU6jIHhQABE71Yr5iVD3t6PlvpRkT3ZW8qE5Y97R4fc7zvOgrSAyDbxvGCqAfYAnxfQIsTob9d2gu8zUggCGQvLEcW3XdxF-FR0g0RcOGXKAoRhOEtg3SktyJMg8L-VVIM1bVSKvZCULQjC3w-YAv1vai73-YUEP1KBUVAqBwJPfCYLgwDRRPJCuMY1DH2fKAsOwHCZM0pieBPYidAxMjrwMyif0uMQgA)